# Cannot change value of select element using enzyme

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

**React:** 16.0.0

**Enzyme:** 3.2.0

**Jest:** 21.2.1

The following test is not working. Also I wrote down the list (in comments) of not working code that I already tried.

```
import React from 'react';
import { configure, mount, shallow, render } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

/* ... */


it('enter valid data for connection; enable proxy; check if button is disabled', () => {
    const component = getComponent(mount); // mount from enzyme
    enterCredentials(component);
    const proxySelect = component.find('select');

    // currently tried these variants:
    proxySelect.simulate('change', { target: { value: true } } );
    // component.find('select').simulate('select', true);
    // component.find('select').simulate('select', 'Yes');
    // component.find('select').simulate('change', { target: { value: true } } );

    // /* Mutating: */
    // proxySelect.node.selectedIndex = 1;
    //
    // Producing this error:
    //
    //      Attempted to access ReactWrapper::node, which was previously a private property on
    //      Enzyme ReactWrapper instances, but is no longer and should not be relied upon.
    //      Consider using the getElement() method instead.
    //
    //  at ReactWrapper.get (node_modules/enzyme/build/ReactWrapper.js:1689:15)

    expect(proxySelect.prop('value')).toBe(true);
    expect(component.find('button').prop('disabled')).toBe(false);
});
```

Markup for select element:

```
<select>
    <option value="false">No</option>
    <option value="true">Yes</option>
</select>
```

Found an issue on github here: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/389
But solutions from that issue isn't working too.
How do you change select's value in tests?

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue is with the type of the "event" `value`, it should be a string like:

```
// notice the quotes around "true"
proxySelect.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'true' } } );
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this approach

```
  wrapper.find('option').at(0).instance().selected = false;
  wrapper.find('option').at(1).instance().selected = true;
```